# How do I get turtles to transfer resources between one another?

Tags: netlogo

My model has 4 breeds:

```
breed [ offices office ]
breed [ service-desks service-desk ]
breed [ employees employee ]
breed [ citizens citizen ]

offices-own [ money ]
employees-own [ money-held ]
citizens-own [ money-received ]
```

In my setup procedure I ask the `offices` and `service-desks` breeds so that I can use a unique shape:

```
  create-offices 1
  ask offices  [
    set shape "building institution"
    set size 4
    set color yellow
    set money num-of-money ]

 ask patch 0 8 [
    sprout 1 [
      set breed service-desks
      set shape "building institution"
      set color pink
      set size 3 ]
```

`offices` has an attribute `money`.

What I am trying to accomplish is that an `employee` will go to the `office` and collect `money`. Then will travel to a `service-desk` where they will meet with a `citizen` breed to handover they money they hold.

What I've tried is:

```
to employee-give-money
  
  ask employees [
    if any? citizens in-radius 1 [
      
      set money-held money-held - 1
      
    ]
    
  ]
  
  ask citizens [
    set money-received money-received + 1
    
    set color orange 
    
  ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic transaction of resources is pretty simple to code with addition and subtraction. Below I have a sample code for how it works.
You might want to build in some safeties in `take-money` so that a turtle can't have negative money.

```
turtles-own [money]

to setup
  
  ca
  crt 5 [
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set money random 1000
  ]
  
end

to test
  
  ask turtle 0 [take-money turtle 1 500]
  
end


to take-money [ from-who amount ]
  
  ask from-who [ set money money - amount ]
  set money money + amount
  
end
```

This snippet of code is to visualise the money all turtles have in order of their who. I used it in a monitor on the interface to make sure everything was happening as intended.

```
to-report turtle-assets
  
  let new-list []
  foreach sort turtles [the-turtle -> ask the-turtle [set new-list lput money new-list]]
  report new-list
  
end
```

Now that the basics are out of the way, let's look at your case.
`if turtle shape = ...` doesn't work because there is no such thing as `turtle shape`. The variable is just `shape`. But anyway, you are already working with breeds, so there is no need to bother with shapes at all. You can use the [`<breeds>-here`](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#turtles-here)  reporter to let agents interact with other local agents. In your case the `employees` want to interact with the `offices-here`.

```
to collect-paycheck
    ask employees [
        if any? offices-here [
            take-money one-of offices-here 500 ;or however much you want them to take
            ]
        ]
end
```

This code will let each employee take 500 money from a random office on their own patch (I assume only 1 office per patch though) each time it is called.

Comment: I've tried to apply your basic principles in my code, and I can't get it to work, because I think my use case is a little bit different. I think you have a good idea of my whole bit of code from another question I submitted, but in terms of this issue, what I am trying to accomplish is that the `employee` transfers resources to a `citizen` that happens to be in the same vicinity. Whereas your code snippet is much more targeted

Comment: I updated my original post to reflect the code that I've tried

Comment: My take-money uses a specific turtle in the example, but you could just as well write `take-money one-of turtles-on neighbors 500`, which uses the same procedure to take money from a random turtle on one of the neighboring tiles.

Comment: the `take-money` procedure can also be rewritten into a `give-money` procedure with minimal effort, in case you want the active turtle to be a different one.

Comment: I think i dont understand how the `[ from-who amount ]` portion of your code works. In your example, the ask is of a specific turtle to give resources to another specific turtle. In my model, the turtles meet at the same place, and its at that point that an exchange occurs randomly between turtles that have resources and those that dont

Comment: @premiumcopypaper You also want to take money from a specific turtle. You just want to choose which turtle that specific turtle is randomly depending on a few circumstances (location, role, money).

Comment: correct, so I tried to do that with the updated code I dropped above, but it doesnt seem to work, there is no transfer of resources

Comment: @premiumcopypaper Have you tried adding some print statements to your code? That is an easy way to figure out what parts of your code are being called and what parts are not being called. I suspect that the condition you use for them finding eachother is not working

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out an option that is more relevant to the model that I am building an could be extensible for other models where there needs to be a transfer of resources.

The basic snippet is:

```
to citizen-take-money
 
  ask citizens [
   
    if any? employees in-radius 2 [
      ask employees [
        set money money - 1
      ]
      set money money + 1
    ]
    
    
    
    ]
  
end
```

The `in-radius` parameter can be adjusted and can work with `neighbors` as well.

Here is a basic model that leverages the above snippet:

```
breed [ employees employee ]
breed [ citizens citizen ]

turtles-own [ money ]

to setup
 
  clear-all
 
  create-employees 1 [
   
    set color green
    set shape "person"
    set size 2
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set money 50
    
  ]
 
  create-citizens 1 [
   
    set color yellow
    set shape "person"
    set size 2
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set label money
  ]
 
end

to go
 
  ask employees [ set label money ] 
  ask citizens [ set label money ]
  employee-movement
  citizen-movement
  citizen-take-money
 
end

to employee-movement
 
  ask employees [
   
    let target patch 0 0
   
    if money > 0 [
     
      face target
     
      move-to target
     
    ]
   
    walk-employee
   
   
  ]
end

to walk-employee
 
  ask employees [
   
    rt random 360
   
    fd 1
   
  ]
 
end

to citizen-movement
 
  ask citizens [
   
    let target patch 0 0
   
    if money = 0 [
     
      face target
     
      move-to target
     
    ]
   
    walk-citizen
   
  ]

end



to walk-citizen
 
  ask citizens [
   
    rt random 360
   
    fd 1
   
  ]
 
end
 
to citizen-take-money
 
  ask citizens [
   
    if any? employees in-radius 2 [
      ask employees [
        set money money - 1
      ]
      set money money + 1
    ]
    
    
    
  ]
  
end
```